# How can I surface TOC items within docfx that are not directly tied to content?

Tags: docfx

I am in the process of [porting the NUnit docs from their GitHub wiki to docfx](https://github.com/nunit/docs/projects/1).

I am trying to understand if this is expected behavior or if there is something I can do within my config file to prevent it.

1. Pull `nunit/docs` repo
2. `cd docs`
3. `docfx build; docfx serve`

### Actual Behavior

Articles are shown for "runn" because the content article titles contain that phrase

> [image]

Articles are shown for "runner" because the content article titles contain that phrase

> [image]

Articles are not shown for "running" because none of the content article titles contain that word, even though the TOC item does

> [image]

### Expected Behavior

I'd like the "Running Tests" item to show up at least -- preferably with the content pages underneath it as well.

---

How do I get these TOC items to surface in the search? Do I need to add content to them so they are treated as pages?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out -- it [appears the `topicHref` is what I'm looking for in these cases](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/intro_toc.html#link-to-another-toc-file).

In my example above, I modified my `toc.yml` to set the `topicHref` to be the first item in the child `toc.yml` file.

```yaml
- name: Running Tests
  href: running-tests/toc.yml
  topicHref: running-tests/Console-Runner.md
```

Now, when I search for "Running" as above, I see the expected result:

> [image]